# Git remote disappearance and inconsistency

Tags: git

- I copied a file to local **.git/config**, to update my local user config for a project.
- Afterwards, all remotes "disappeared" (kind of)
- `git remote` is empty, as is any remote-tracking information.
- Local **.git/refs/remotes** shows the old remotes, as does `git branch --remote`

How to recover the state of the repo?

Comment: So you mean you lost the original config? If that's the case there's no recovery mechanism in `Git` for the config file as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .git/config file is local only, not tracked by Git.

If you remember the URL for those remotes, you would need to add them back manually:

```
git remote add origin /url/remote/repo
git remote add upstream(or any other remote name) /url/upstream/repo
...
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you.